# React JS : Get data from api and send to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm a little bit lost. I want to get a response from my API and send the data to a child component. It seems that I don't understand how to do that because it says to me : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Can you explain to me how can I do it ?
Here is a snippet of my code :

```
function GetData(url, params, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url + '?' + params, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if (this.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                console.log('error');
           }
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}

class Utilisateurs extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {users:''}
        GetData('http://localhost:3333/shop/users', 'login=true', 
            function(res) {
               this.setState({users: res});
            }
        )

    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div id="center">             
            <UserListSorted data={this.state.users}></UserListSorted>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So I make a GET request and I want to change the state of 'users' with the response so I can print a list of users. But I don't know how to fix this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `GetData` is out of scope. make it an arrow function instead and you should be fine

Comment: try to put GETDATA method inside of class scope

Answer (score 1):

The `this` context in `this.setState` isn't what you think it is. You *can* reassign `this` to a new variable outside of the closure, but it's a lot easier if you use an arrow function (which has no `this` and borrows the context from the outer scope) instead:

```
GetData('http://localhost:3333/shop/users', 'login=true', (res) => {
  this.setState({ users: res });
});
```

Aside: while you *can* perform fetch operations in the constructor [the React team recommend that you use `componentDidMount`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9021#issuecomment-280677070) instead. There's more information [in this article](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/).

Oh, you you might think about using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of writing all that XMLHTTPRequest code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple things going on here.

First, you shouldn't make network requests in the `constructor` or `componentWillMount()`. Someone will probably call it an anti-pattern.

You shouldn't ever do any long running tasks from the `constructor` because it will make the component take longer to load. It is a good general rule. Just use it to set variables and properties and trigger other class methods, quick setup. I can't remember exactly, but it's probably an issue with synchronous vs. asynchronous behaviour. The constructor is a method. It is a function, so if you hang the thread waiting for network request, the component has to wait before it can continue.

The same is true for `componentWillMount()`. That lifecycle method kicks off before the component is mounted in the DOM, which means if you make a network request and it **completes** before the component is mounted, there is nothing to setState on. There is no component in the DOM yet to setState. This is what someone told me before and it stuck with me. I am just telling you now to hopefully give you that same moment of realization.

You could do it from `componentDidMount()` because the component is ready, but it will trigger another re-render if you call `this.setState()` from inside that lifecycle method. Some call "setState inside componentDidMount" an anti-pattern, but its not really that bad. I would say use it, but be aware that it does trigger a re-render. The render method will run at least twice. If you had a big, complex component or lots of them, it could cause performance issue. That's why people say "don't do it".

Moving forward, I would recommend creating a class method called `getData()` or something and call that from `componentDidMount()`. Something like this:

```
class Something extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: '',
    }
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    this.getData()
  }

 getData() {
  // get data from server
  const theData = 'we got some data'
  this.setState({
    data: theData,
  })
 }

 render() {
   return <div>{this.state.data}</div>
 }
}
```

I actually can't exactly help you with the XHR request because its been al ong time since I used it. I can't verify if your syntax is correct. I would recommend using a library called `request` https://www.npmjs.com/package/request. I imagine the XHR request will work fine, but check out request as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the context of `this`, inside GetData function it's undefined, so try using arrow function for your callback `() => {}` which automatically binds `this` context from `Utilisateurs` class.

```
GetData(
  'http://localhost:3333/shop/users',
  'login=true', 
  res => {
    this.setState({users: res});
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do your api calls in `componentDidMount` (in addition to use an arrow function as the callback of `GetData()`) :

```
class Utilisateurs extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {users:''}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        GetData('http://localhost:3333/shop/users', 'login=true', 
            (res) => {
               this.setState({users: res});
            }
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <div id="center">             
            <UserListSorted data={this.state.users}></UserListSorted>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit :** Actually `componentDidMount` is recommended in [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#where-in-the-component-lifecycle-should-i-make-an-ajax-call), they don't explains why unfortunately, but some articles about best practices in React tells that fetching before the first render can lead in issues some cases.

Comment: Might be useful to explain _why_.

Comment: @Andy you're right, i edited my post but this is actually hard to get the reason.